# Bresenham's algorithm

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, vector-graphics

How to find the decision parameter for drawing different functions like parabola, sine curve,  bell curve?
Please tell me about the approach why do we sometimes multiply by constant? 
For Example

1. in case of ellipse, p = a^2(d1 - d2),p = b^2(d1 - d2) for upper and lower half region
   respectively where a, b constants
2. in case of line, p =  deltax(d1 - d2) where p is decision parameter d1,d2 are
   distances,deltax is constant and is equal to xend - xstart

why not only take (d1 -d2) as parameter

Answer (score 1):

Bresenham's algorithm as stated by the OP is a bit amiss, but I assume the following.

The decision parameter *could* adjust `d1 - d2` and not scale by some constant as you suggest were it not for the initialization of the decision parameter.  It is not generally scalable by that constant.

```
// code from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm
plotLine(x0,y0, x1,y1)
  dx=x1-x0
  dy=y1-y0

  D = 2*dy - dx   // Not scalable by 2
  plot(x0,y0)
  y=y0

  for x from x0+1 to x1
    if D > 0
      y = y+1
      plot(x,y)
      D = D + (2*dy-2*dx)  // Scalable by 2
    else
      plot(x,y)
      D = D + (2*dy)  // Scalable by 2
```